# Firebase query not returning anything

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

This has been a headscratcher for me recently so this is
my firebase structure
[image: my firebase structure]

**Note that, it enters the `onDataChange`**

```
var userPrefix: String = getUserPrefix()
    Log.d("usePRef",userPrefix + " x ")

    var sp: SimPrefix //SimPrefix Data Class
    var query: Query = mDatabaseReference.child("simnumbers")
            .orderByChild("simPref")
            .equalTo(userPrefix)
            .limitToFirst(1)

    query.addValueEventListener( object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (finalSnap in dataSnapshot.children) {
                sp = finalSnap.getValue(SimPrefix::class.java)!! //passing the object to another
                                                                //data class object
                resultView.text = sp.simCard // displaying the value to a TextView
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            println("loadPost:onCancelled ${databaseError.toException()}")
        }
    })
}
```

However, the firebase query is not returning anything.

Comment: What is the structure of your `SimPrefix` class?

Comment: And what do you get if you omit the `orderByChild("simPref")` from the query? Do you get anything then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i provide java code you can change your according and put value.

```
 private void sqlQuery(){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = reference.child("simnumbers").child(mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey()).orderByChild("simPref").equalTo("value");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("Value::",issue.getValue(User.class).email);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not Java. The language is Kotlin.

Comment: when you paste java code into kotlin class it automatically converts into kotlin.

Comment: Thanks! I programmed in java before I was trying kotlin now so I understood this anyways. Thanks a lot!